# Powershell add like rows together value in column 2

Tags: loops, powershell, csv, sum

I have been searching for a way to do this in PowerShell, but I have had no luck. I have a file that looks like this.

```
Column1,column2
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
A,2
B,3
D,6
A,3
C,2
```

I would like to find a way that I could sort through this file and add column2 and end up with a file that would look like this.

```
column1,column2
A,6
B,5
C,5
D,10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Group-Object would be the first friend I would consult for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) and [`Measure-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) would accomplish this for you. Provided you have PowerShell 3.0 or higher...

```powershell
Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv | Group-Object Column1 | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Column1 = $_.Name
        Column2 =  $_.Group.Column2 | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\testOutput.csv
```

If you have issues with either of these cmdlets please consult the documentation or debug my script to see what it is doing.

Could also use calculated properties with the similar logic and same output. Should work on lower PowerShell versions as well.

```powershell
Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv | 
    Group-Object Column1 | 
    Select @{Label="Column1";Expression={$_.Name}},@{Label="Column2";Expression={$_.Group.Column2 | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum}} |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\testOutput.csv
```